# Who is captain of the Enterprise in the TNG episode "Tapestry"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode "Tapestry" of TNG, Picard’s life is changed by Q. In Picard’s alternate life, who is captain of the Enterprise? Was is Jellico? Or someone else?

Answer (score 8):

"Lieutenant" Picard asks Commander Data this *exact* question in the episode ([script link](http://chakoteya.net/NextGen/241.htm)):

> PICARD: Who's the captain of this ship?
>   DATA: **[Captain Thomas Halloway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Halloway)**. Perhaps I should escort you to Sickbay.

According to the *Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion* (as quoted by MA wiki so #grainofsalt):

> "Halloway was never actually seen, and for a time the "Tapestry"
>   writers considered referring to Edward Jellico as the Enterprise
>   captain in the altered future. (Star Trek: The Next Generation
>   Companion)"

Comment: *"_Unaware of Bob Justman’s formative idea to credit the ban on captains’ dangerous beam-downs to Picard, Moore said the brief mention of just such an instance with Picard taking command was meant to show that his “twenty-two-year mission” on his old ship as laid out in GR’s original Writer’s Guide was not all spent as captain. Also, he added, the stabbing is not the major event Boothby talks of in “The First Duty” (219), and **Jellico (“Chain of Command” 236-37) was his later-nixed first choice for Enterprise’s captain in Picard’s altered future**."* - Sayeth the TNG Companion